# Lebesgue measure of complement of this set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question was part of  my real analysis quiz and I need help in correctly proving it.

> For each a $\in \mathbb{R}$ , let $ S_a$ ={$(x,y,z)\in {\mathbb{R}}^3 | x^2+y^2+z^2= a^2$} Let $E=\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Q}} S_a$ Then does every open set containing $E^C$ has finite Lebesgue measure ?

I can't think why measure must be finite , even intutively I think that measure must be infinite. I am looking for a rigorious argument why measure must be finite. I am not really good in Lebesgue measure but really want to learn.

Comment: Your claim is false. For example, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing $E^C$ and does not have finite measure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(edit)** I assume you meant to say that there is not open set **contained** in E, with positive measure, so I answered that question.

E is $\mathbb{R}^3$, except for the points with rational norm ( $||\mathbf{x}||\in \mathbb{Q}\Rightarrow \mathbf{x}\notin E$).
The idea here is that, $F:=\mathbb{R}^3-E$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (and $\overline{F}=\mathbb{R}^3$)
Then, you can show that, there are no open sets in $E$, with non cero messure, since they would intersect with $F$.

Let me know if you need more details.